# How we fetch audio from microphone in newly created vs code plugin

Tags: typescript, plugins, vscode-extensions

How we fetch audio from microphone in newly created vs code plugin no packages is working as expected in typescript language

I have tried several package that works on node js environment but not working in plugin development environment